# How to run a specific test in a robot frame work with test name contains space

Tags: robotframework

How to run a specific test in a robot frame work with test name contains space eg: **test case 1** . I used "robot -t test case 1 poc.robot.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out test case name under double quotes worked.
robot -t ***"test case 1"*** poc.robot